# Trouble with simple example of React Hooks useCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to make a simple example that follows the React Hooks example in the doc at page https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback

Without `useCallback` the code works find as is in this example:

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";

function Test(props) {
  function doSomething(a, b) {
    console.log("doSomething called");
    return a + b;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {Array.from({ length: 3 }).map(() => (
        <div>{doSomething('aaa','bbb')}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

However, when I add what I think is the right code for `useCallback` as follows, I get an error (a is not defined)

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";

function Test(props) {
  function doSomething(a, b) {
    console.log("doSomething called");
    return a + b;
  }

  const memoizedCallback = useCallback(
    () => {
      doSomething(a, b);
    },
    [a, b]
  );

  return (
    <div>
      {Array.from({ length: 3 }).map(() => (
        <div>{memoizedCallback("aaa", "bbb")}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

The problem code is here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-usememo2?file=Hello.js

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The intent of `useCallback` is to be able to leverage props or state that are in the current scope and that may change on re-render. The dependency-array then tells React when you need a new version of the callback. If you are trying to memoize an expensive computation, you need to use `useMemo` instead.

The example below demonstrates the differences between `useCallback` and `useMemo` and the consequences of not using them. In this example I am using [`React.memo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) to prevent `Child` from re-rendering unless its props or state change. This allows seeing the benefits of `useCallback`. Now if `Child` receives a new `onClick` prop it will cause a re-render.

Child 1 is receiving a non-memoized `onClick` callback, so whenever the parent component re-renders, Child 1 always receives a new `onClick` function so it is forced to re-render.

Child 2 is using a memoized `onClick` callback returned from `useCallback` and Child 3 is using the equivalent via `useMemo` to demonstrate the meaning of

> useCallback(fn, inputs) is equivalent to useMemo(() => fn, inputs)

For Child 2 and 3 the callback still gets executed every time you click on Child 2 or 3, `useCallback` just ensures that the same version of the `onClick` function is passed when the dependencies haven't changed.

The following part of the display helps point out what is happening:

> nonMemoizedCallback === memoizedCallback: false|true

Separately, I'm displaying `somethingExpensiveBasedOnA` and a memoized version using `useMemo`. For demonstration purposes I'm using an incorrect dependency array (I intentionally left out `b`) so that you can see that the memoized version doesn't change when `b` changes, but it does change when `a` changes. The non-memoized version changes whenever `a` or `b` change.

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import React, {
  useRef,
  useMemo,
  useEffect,
  useState,
  useCallback
} from "react";

const Child = React.memo(({ onClick, suffix }) => {
  const numRendersRef = useRef(1);
  useEffect(() => {
    numRendersRef.current++;
  });

  return (
    <div onClick={() => onClick(suffix)}>
      Click Me to log a and {suffix} and change b. Number of Renders:{" "}
      {numRendersRef.current}
    </div>
  );
});
function App(props) {
  const [a, setA] = useState("aaa");
  const [b, setB] = useState("bbb");

  const computeSomethingExpensiveBasedOnA = () => {
    console.log("recomputing expensive thing", a);
    return a + b;
  };
  const somethingExpensiveBasedOnA = computeSomethingExpensiveBasedOnA();
  const memoizedSomethingExpensiveBasedOnA = useMemo(
    () => computeSomethingExpensiveBasedOnA(),
    [a]
  );
  const nonMemoizedCallback = suffix => {
    console.log(a + suffix);
    setB(prev => prev + "b");
  };
  const memoizedCallback = useCallback(nonMemoizedCallback, [a]);
  const memoizedCallbackUsingMemo = useMemo(() => nonMemoizedCallback, [a]);
  return (
    <div>
      A: {a}
      <br />
      B: {b}
      <br />
      nonMemoizedCallback === memoizedCallback:{" "}
      {String(nonMemoizedCallback === memoizedCallback)}
      <br />
      somethingExpensiveBasedOnA: {somethingExpensiveBasedOnA}
      <br />
      memoizedSomethingExpensiveBasedOnA: {memoizedSomethingExpensiveBasedOnA}
      <br />
      <br />
      <div onClick={() => setA(a + "a")}>Click Me to change a</div>
      <br />
      <Child onClick={nonMemoizedCallback} suffix="1" />
      <Child onClick={memoizedCallback} suffix="2" />
      <Child onClick={memoizedCallbackUsingMemo} suffix="3" />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit useCallback and useMemo]

Here's a related answer: [React Hooks useCallback causes child to re-render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55045566/react-hooks-usecallback-causes-child-to-re-render/55047178#55047178)

Comment: On the first example, it still outputs the console.log 3 times. What am I not getting? (hard question I guess)

Comment: You're just misunderstanding the purpose of `useCallback`. `useCallback` does not memoize the results of the function -- it memoizes the function itself. In the first example there is no good reason to use it, but in the second example it would prevent the `onClick` property of `Child` from changing on re-renders. If you want to memoize the results (to prevent redundant executions of an expensive function), you should be be using [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo).

Comment: you are so right I don't get it. I'm stymied by this comment in the docs:  `useCallback(fn, inputs) is equivalent to useMemo(() => fn, inputs).`  I'm putting courseware together and am a little lost, looking for good examples.

Comment: I've replaced my example with one that is no longer based on your code, but that should help clear things up if you spend enough time studying it, interacting with it, and viewing the results.