# React Hooks - How to avoid redeclaring functions on every render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

On a react class I would write something like this

```
class Myclass extends React.Component {
  handleUpdate = info => {
    //do the update
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <SomeMarkup>
        <SomeComponent onUpdate={this.handleUpdate} />
      </SomeMarkup>
    )
  }
}
```

If using a function I could just write the following

```
function MyFunction() {
  function handleUpdate(info) {
    // do the update
  }
  return (
    <SomeMarkup>
      <SomeComponent onUpdate={handleUpdate} />
    </SomeMarkup>
  )
}
```

...but with that I'd be redeclaring a function on every render. Is there any sort of trick that would memoize the handler function between renders? Or should I just move the handler out of the render scope? (Moving it out of the render scope requires me that I explicitly pass more parameters since I wont directly have access to the function scope.)

Comment: Use a arrow function i heard its better for the memory

Comment: arrow function only changes the scope of `this`, which is irrelevant for "non-classes"

Comment: You are right, arrow functions are good for not binding every time. Back to your question, the only way to not recreate it every time is to pass it as a prop. It will use the function but not recreate it. That is the only way.

Comment: is there a strong need here to avoid redeclaring the functions? any performance issue that's cropping up?

Comment: performance issues related to big renders can easily show up when dealing with things like big controlled forms, where every keystroke may trigger 1 (or more) rerenders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is exactly the scenario that [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) is for. The function still gets declared every time with `useCallback`, but the function returned is memoized so that if it is passed as a property to children, the children will receive a consistent function unless it has to change due to dependencies changing.

Please see my recent related answer here that demonstrates in detail how `useCallback` works:
[Trouble with simple example of React Hooks useCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932674/trouble-with-simple-example-of-react-hooks-usecallback/54934164#54934164)

Here's another related answer: [React Hooks useCallback causes child to re-render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55045566/react-hooks-usecallback-causes-child-to-re-render/55047178#55047178)