# React Hooks useCallback causes child to re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to turn from class components to functional components using the new Hooks. However it feels that with `useCallback` I will get unnecessary renders of children unlike with class functions in class components.

Below I have two relatively simple snippets. The first is my example written as classes, and the second is my example re-written as functional components. The goal is to get the same behaviour with functional components as with class components.

**Class component test-case**

```js
class Block extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    console.log("Rendering block: ", this.props.color);

    return (
        <div onClick={this.props.onBlockClick}
          style = {
            {
              width: '200px',
              height: '100px',
              marginTop: '12px',
              backgroundColor: this.props.color,
              textAlign: 'center'
            }
          }>
          {this.props.text}
         </div>
    );
  }
};

class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  }
  
  
  onClick = () => {
    console.log("I've been clicked when count was: ", this.state.count);
  }
  
  updateCount = () => {
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1});
  };
  
  render() {
    console.log("Rendering Example. Count: ", this.state.count);
    
    return (
      <div style={{ display: 'flex', 'flexDirection': 'row'}}>
        <Block onBlockClick={this.onClick} text={'Click me to log the count!'} color={'orange'}/>
        <Block onBlockClick={this.updateCount} text={'Click me to add to the count'} color={'red'}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root' style='width: 100%; height: 100%'>
</div>
```

**Functional component test-case**

```js
const Block = React.memo((props) => {
  console.log("Rendering block: ", props.color);
  
  return (
      <div onClick={props.onBlockClick}
        style = {
          {
            width: '200px',
            height: '100px',
            marginTop: '12px',
            backgroundColor: props.color,
            textAlign: 'center'
          }
        }>
        {props.text}
       </div>
  );
});

const Example = () => {
  const [ count, setCount ] = React.useState(0);
  console.log("Rendering Example. Count: ", count);
  
  const onClickWithout = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log("I've been clicked when count was: ", count);
  }, []);
  
  const onClickWith = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log("I've been clicked when count was: ", count);
  }, [ count ]);
  
  const updateCount = React.useCallback(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, [ count ]);
  
  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', 'flexDirection': 'row'}}>
      <Block onBlockClick={onClickWithout} text={'Click me to log with empty array as input'} color={'orange'}/>
      <Block onBlockClick={onClickWith} text={'Click me to log with count as input'} color={'cyan'}/>
      <Block onBlockClick={updateCount} text={'Click me to add to the count'} color={'red'}/>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root' style='width: 100%; height: 100%'>
</div>
```

In the first one(class components) I can update the count via the red block without re-rendering either of the blocks, and I can freely console log the current count via the orange block.

In the second one(functional components) updating the count via the red-block will trigger a re-render of both the red and cyan block. This is because the `useCallback` will make a new instance of it's function because the count has changed, causing the blocks to get a new `onClick` prop and thus re-render. The orange block won't re-render because the `useCallback` used for the orange `onClick` does not depend on the count value. This would be good but the orange block will not show the actual value of the count when you click on it.

I thought the point of having `useCallback` was so that children don't get new instances of the same function and don't have unnecessary re-renders, but that seems to happen anyways the second the callback function uses a single variable which happens quite often if not always from my experience.

So how would I go about making this `onClick` function within a functional component without having the children re-render? Is it at all possible?

**Update (solution):**
Using Ryan Cogswell's answer below I've crafted a custom hook to make creating class-like functions easily.

```
const useMemoizedCallback = (callback, inputs = []) => {
    // Instance var to hold the actual callback.
    const callbackRef = React.useRef(callback);
    
    // The memoized callback that won't change and calls the changed callbackRef.
    const memoizedCallback = React.useCallback((...args) => {
      return callbackRef.current(...args);
    }, []);

    // The callback that is constantly updated according to the inputs.
    const updatedCallback = React.useCallback(callback, inputs);

    // The effect updates the callbackRef depending on the inputs.
    React.useEffect(() => {
        callbackRef.current = updatedCallback;
    }, inputs);

    // Return the memoized callback.
    return memoizedCallback;
};
```

I can then use this in the function component very easily like so and simply pass the onClick to the child. It will no longer re-render the child but still make use of updated vars.

```
const onClick = useMemoizedCallback(() => {
    console.log("NEW I've been clicked when count was: ", count);
}, [count]);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`useCallback` will avoid unnecessary child re-renders due to something changing in the parent that is **not** part of the dependencies for the callback. In order to avoid child re-renders when the callback's dependencies are involved, you need to use a ref. Ref's are the hook equivalent to an instance variable.

Below I have `onClickMemoized` using the `onClickRef` which points at the current `onClick` (set via `useEffect`) so that it delegates to a version of the function that knows the current value of the state.

I also changed `updateCount` to use the functional update syntax so that it doesn't need to have a dependency on `count`.

```js
const Block = React.memo(props => {
  console.log("Rendering block: ", props.color);

  return (
    <div
      onClick={props.onBlockClick}
      style={{
        width: "200px",
        height: "100px",
        marginTop: "12px",
        backgroundColor: props.color,
        textAlign: "center"
      }}
    >
      {props.text}
    </div>
  );
});

const Example = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  console.log("Rendering Example. Count: ", count);

  const onClick = () => {
    console.log("I've been clicked when count was: ", count);
  };
  const onClickRef = React.useRef(onClick);
  React.useEffect(
    () => {
      // By leaving off the dependency array parameter, it means that
      // this effect will execute after every committed render, so
      // onClickRef.current will stay up-to-date.
      onClickRef.current = onClick;
    }
  );

  const onClickMemoized = React.useCallback(() => {
    onClickRef.current();
  }, []);

  const updateCount = React.useCallback(() => {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
      <Block
        onBlockClick={onClickMemoized}
        text={"Click me to log with empty array as input"}
        color={"orange"}
      />
      <Block
        onBlockClick={updateCount}
        text={"Click me to add to the count"}
        color={"red"}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id='root' style='width: 100%; height: 100%'>
</div>
```

And, of course, the beauty of hooks is that you can factor out this stateful logic into a custom hook:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Block = React.memo(props => {
  console.log("Rendering block: ", props.color);

  return (
    <div
      onClick={props.onBlockClick}
      style={{
        width: "200px",
        height: "100px",
        marginTop: "12px",
        backgroundColor: props.color,
        textAlign: "center"
      }}
    >
      {props.text}
    </div>
  );
});

const useCount = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  const logCount = () => {
    console.log("I've been clicked when count was: ", count);
  };
  const logCountRef = React.useRef(logCount);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // By leaving off the dependency array parameter, it means that
    // this effect will execute after every committed render, so
    // logCountRef.current will stay up-to-date.
    logCountRef.current = logCount;
  });

  const logCountMemoized = React.useCallback(() => {
    logCountRef.current();
  }, []);

  const updateCount = React.useCallback(() => {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
  }, []);
  return { count, logCount: logCountMemoized, updateCount };
};
const Example = () => {
  const { count, logCount, updateCount } = useCount();
  console.log("Rendering Example. Count: ", count);

  return (
    <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
      <Block
        onBlockClick={logCount}
        text={"Click me to log with empty array as input"}
        color={"orange"}
      />
      <Block
        onBlockClick={updateCount}
        text={"Click me to add to the count"}
        color={"red"}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<Example />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit useCallback and useRef]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do find it pretty tedious that what can be done in a class component with a singular function would in this functional component take the actual function, 1 ref to store the function in an instance var, 1 memoized function to pass to the child, and 1 `useEffect` to update the instance var. Before I accept this as answer I was wondering if you think it's possible to put these 4 in a custom hook so it remains a simple singular function call?

Comment: Yes, that's where the beauty of hooks shines. Answer updated.

Comment: It looks beautiful, the sandbox has an error though but I can definitely work with this!

Comment: I forgot to save the latest version of my sandbox -- link updated.

Comment: If you are using eslint for the hook. You will see that logCount function is required wrapped in useCallback with count parameter.

Comment: @LongNguyen Thanks, I have addressed the eslint warning by removing the dependency array on the `useEffect` which sets the ref.

Comment: Why not put `logCountRef.current = logCount;` outside of `useEffect`?

Comment: @mowwwalker Because render shouldn't have any side effects (such as setting a ref) since the render might not be committed; whereas the effect only gets executed if the render has been committed to the DOM.

Comment: @RyanCogswell that makes sense, thanks! Any recommended reading on that?

Comment: @mowwwalker I've read about it in numerous places, but I don't have a good reference to point you to. Articles about preparing for StrictMode and concurrent rendering will touch on it. I follow several of the React team on Twitter and have seen some related conversations there (e.g. search Twitter for "@sebmarkbage ref").

Comment: wow.. this is awesome. thank you for saving my life LOL

Answer (score 1):

This works too with minimal change in the current code.

- The deps parameters from useCallback is removed
- update the ref value when state changes
- Instead of using the value from the state use it from ref inside `useCallback` block since the deps is removed and the state value will not be update.

```js
const {useState} = React

const Block = React.memo((props) => {
  console.log("Rendering block: ", props.color);
  
  return (
      <div onClick={props.onBlockClick}
        style = {
          {
            width: '200px',
            height: '100px',
            marginTop: '12px',
            backgroundColor: props.color,
            textAlign: 'center'
          }
        }>
        {props.text}
       </div>
  );
});

const Example = () => {
  const [ count, setCount ] = useState(0);
  
  const countRef = React.useRef(count);
  console.log("Rendering Example. Count: ", count);
  
  const onClickWithout = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log("I've been clicked when count was: ", count, countRef.current);
  }, []);
  
  const onClickWith = React.useCallback(() => {
    console.log("I've been clicked when count was: ", count, countRef.current);
  }, [ ]);
  
  const updateCount = React.useCallback(() => {
    setCount(count => { 
      countRef.current = count+1
      return count + 1 
    });
  }, [ ]);
  
  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', 'flexDirection': 'row'}}>
      <Block onBlockClick={onClickWithout} text={'Click me to log with empty array as input'} color={'orange'}/>
      <Block onBlockClick={onClickWith} text={'Click me to log with count as input'} color={'cyan'}/>
      <Block onBlockClick={updateCount} text={'Click me to add to the count'} color={'red'}/>
    </div>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render( <Example /> , document.getElementById("react"));
//ReactDOM.render( < Example / > , document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```