# Prevent re-render when sending function prop from functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

When sending props to a `PureComponent` or a functional component, you can optimize performance by using props that don't change for every render, which will prevent the component from re-rendering.

When using class components this is simple:

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <List createRows={this.createRows}/>;
  }

  createRows = () => this.props.data.map(dataToRow);
}
```

Given `List` being either a `PureCompoment` or a functional component, the `createRows` prop will never cause a re-render of `List`.

---

But if the `Component` is a functional component, this is no longer possible:

```
  function Component(props) {
    return <List createRows={createRows}/>;

    function createRows() {
      return props.data.map(dataToRow);
    }
  }
```

Since `createRows` is created every time `Component` renders, the prop will change, causing a re-render of `List` every time `Component` is re-rendered. This can cause a big loss in performance. Notice also that the `createRows` cannot be placed outside the functional component, since it is dependent on the `data` prop of `List`.

---

Now, with the introduction on Hooks, it is possible to hold the `createRows` in a `useState` hook:

```
  function Component(props) {
    const [ createRows ] = useState(() => () =>
      props.data.map(dataToRow);
    );

    return <List createRows={createRows}/>;
  }
```

Since the `createRows` is saved in a state hook, it will not change with each render, and no re-render of `List` will occour, like we want.

However, this seems more like a hack than a solution.

---

**What is best practice for sending a function prop from a functional components to a child component, without causing unnecessary re-renders of the child component?**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`useCallback`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback) hook exists exactly to solve this problem. I advise you to carefully read the official [guide to hooks](https://react.dev/reference/react/hooks), it pretty much answers all possible questions

```
  function Component(props) {
    const createRows = useCallback(() =>
      props.data.map(dataToRow);
    ), []); // provide dependencies here

    return <List createRows={createRows}/>;
  }
```

Comment: what if the child needs to provide some argument when calling the callback? Must we then use `useReducer`? Curious why `useCallback` API didn't allow for any arguments to be passed...

Comment: You can specify any arguments you want for a function that you pass to `useCallback`. You basically create a custom function here with any amount of parameters. It's just in this particular case we didn't need any arguments for this callback function

Comment: Can you provide a solution to my similar issue ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72176305/changing-props-state-using-api-causes-infinite-loop/72186468#72186468

Comment: Here are the newer docs: https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback

Answer (score 2):

This is the purpose of [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback). You can find more details in some of my related answers below.

[Trouble with simple example of React Hooks useCallback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54932674/trouble-with-simple-example-of-react-hooks-usecallback/54934164#54934164)

[What is the intension of using React's useCallback hook in place of useEffect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54371244/what-is-the-intension-of-using-reacts-usecallback-hook-in-place-of-useeffect/54372172#54372172)

[React Hooks useCallback causes child to re-render](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55045566/react-hooks-usecallback-causes-child-to-re-render/55047178#55047178)