# useCallback vs. useMemo and when to use them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

What is the main difference between `useCallback` and `useMemo`?
And when to use `useCallback` of React Hooks?

Comment: Related - [What is the intention of using React's useCallback hook in place of useEffect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54371244/104380)

Answer (score 9):

```js
useMemo(() => (bar) => foo + bar, [foo]);
```

Equivalent code with useCallback:

```
useCallback((bar) => foo + bar, [foo]);
```

Use callback is **just a shorthand** variation of `useMemo` to use with functions.

Here is why it exists:
When you use `useMemo`,the value usually changes when one of its dependencies change. For example:

```
const fullName = useMemo(() => firstName + lastName, [firstName, lastName]);
```

If `firstName` or `lastName` change, `fullName` will also change. On the other hand, functions themselves usually don't need to be recomputed, and their dependencies are mostly closure values that may change.

```
const getFullName = useCallback(() => firstName + lastName, [firstName, lastName]);
```

Here, when `firstName` or `lastName` change, we don't need to have a completely different function with a different body, but we do need to have a new instance of the same function so that it has up to date values in closure (dependencies). So React team just added it for convenience as it is a common use case, and the `() => () =>` syntax is somewhat ugly.

Answer (score 6):

**`useMemo` and `useCallback`** both use something called **memoization** which you can think of it like the hooks are **remembering** something.

---

**The differences:**

**`useMemo`** will memoize/remember the **value** that is returned from the function you pass into it until the dependancies change.

```js
const num = 10
const result = useMemo(() => num + num, [num])
// result is now equal to 20
```

**`useCallback`** will memoize/remember **the actual function** you pass into it until the dependancies change which gives you something called **referential equality**.

```js
const num = 10
const result = useCallback(() => num + num, [num])
// result is now equal to () => num + num.
// result === result between renders.
```

---

**Referential equality:**

```js
() => {} === () => {} // This is false
```

```js
const a = () => {}
a === a // This is true
```

Answer (score -1):

`useMemo` helps prevent re-rendering unless dependencies to a function have changed while `useCallback` helps prevent rerendering unless a function has changed. I.e when a function is to be passed as an argument to another function, `useCallback` will only allow re-rendering after a different function is passed.
Here is a link to a resource that might help explain further

https://btholt.github.io/complete-intro-to-react-v5/hooks-in-depth

Comment: This is not quite correct. `useCallback` doesn't check if function has changed (because it will be declared on each render and will always be different object), and it also accepts a dependency array.just like `useMemo`.